# dir and filesep matlab

Tags: matlab, dir

I am trying to find a list of jpg files but also using filesep (to break the names of the files) in one line

```
dir([folder,[filesep '*.' 'jpg']]).
```

The above command works for me.
But I also want to find the files that include in their name a specific word like *'blue'* but when I tried to use

```
dir([folder,[filesep '*.' '*blue*jpg']])
```

it did not work, the program does not find any files at all. Is there anyway to do this in one line?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `dir([folder,[filesep '*blue*.jpg']])`, or more simply `dir([folder filesep '*blue*.jpg'])`.

---

Just to be clear, the `*` character acts as a "wildcard". It can represent zero or more characters of any kind.

`*.jpg` finds all .jpg files because `*` allows the filename before the extension to be anything.

`red*.jpg` finds all .jpg files starting with `red`, like `redhouse.jpg` or `redflower.jpg`.

`*green.jpg` finds all .jpg files ending with `green`, like `grassgreen.jpg` or `darkgreen.jpg`

`*blue*.jpg` finds all .jpg files that contain the word `blue`, like `skyblue.jpg`, `bluecar.jpg`, or `mybluebox.jpg`.

What you're using now, `dir([folder,[filesep '*.' '*blue*jpg']])` would find files like `something.BLAHblueBLEHjpg`.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html)? This command will take care of the `filesep` for you in a much nicer way:

```
dir( fullfile( folder, '*blue*.jpg' ) );
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I was not aware of this command.